# SQL Different output result set for same query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Why this SQL query produces different output result in SQL 2008R2 and 2012.It seems 2008R2 results for this query looks fine.Why the same sort order is missing in 2012?

```
Declare @TempTable TABLE (Name VARCHAR(25), RankOrder INT)
INSERT INTO @TempTable SELECT 'b', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 'd', 4 UNION ALL SELECT  'a', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 'e', 5 UNION ALL SELECT 'c', 3
SELECT * INTO #ResultTable FROM @TempTable ORDER BY RankOrder
SELECT * FROM #ResultTable
DROP TABLE #ResultTable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SELECT ... INTO <new_table> ...` statement pretty much ignores the `ORDER BY` statement.

From the [INTO clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) documentation, Limitations and Restrictions:

> Specifying an ORDER BY clause does not guarantee the rows are inserted in the specified order.

You then `SELECT` all rows from the temporary table without an `ORDER BY` clause, which also gives no guarantees as to what order you will receive the rows in. You would assume the same order as the rows were inserted, but there was no guarantee as to what that order was either.

In conclusion you cannot expect any specific order in which the rows are returned, and they may differ in different versions of the same RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

We can not tell what order is inside a table by using select * from #ResultTable? There is no guarantee as to the order in a select query.

However, result sets are different on SQL Fiddle in most cases. If you want to guarantee that the result set should be same, then add a primary key. Then the insertion order will remain same :

```
    DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Name VARCHAR(50), SortOrder INT)
    INSERT INTO @TempTable SELECT 'b', 2 UNION ALL SELECT 'c', 3 UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 1 UNION ALL SELECT 'e', 5 UNION ALL SELECT 'd', 4


    SELECT TOP 0 * into #ResultTable from @TempTable;

    ALTER TABLE #ResultTable add id int identity(1, 1) primary key;

    INSERT INTO #ResultTable(name, sortorder)
        SELECT * FROM @TempTable
        ORDER BY SortOrder;

    SELECT * FROM #ResultTable
    DROP TABLE #ResultTable
```

But still I will ignore doing select * from #ResultTable after this. But yes, it does return them in the correct order in both SQL Server 2008 and 2012.

Because SQL Server guarantees that primary keys are inserted in the proper order, the records are also guaranteed will be in correct order in this case.

If you are facing any specific problem in any scenario then please let us know so we will try to sort out the same.

Thank You.

Comment: You are right.The same query needs to be slight modification in diffrent sql version then where does the keyword backward compatblity comes from the higher version?